# Мобильное приложение с пуш уведомлениями на phonegap и nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, phonegap, mobile

Друзья. Сразу хочу описать приблизительно свои способности. На js могу, используя мозг и гугл, сделать что-то не сложное. И я понимаю, как он работает, но практики в чём то серьёзном нет.

У меня есть задумка приложения. Что-то вроде месенджера. Если коротко, то нужно выбирать пользователя из телефонной книги, отправлять ему что-то. Тот, в свою очередь, принимает и может отправлять что-то в ответ. Не хочу отращивать бороду 2 года вникая в Objective C и java. Просто хочу phonegap и свое приложение.

Поэтому прошу дать какой-нибудь общий алгоритм того, что для этого нужно или накидать каких нибудь советов, которые будут содержать ключевые слова, которые дадут направление в гуглении.

Сразу хочу сказать, что я не прошу всё продумать за меня. Просто буду рад любому сообщению.

Сейчас у меня только смутное представление о том что нужно приложение как-то привязывать к одному пользователю. Нужен сервер, который как-то будет принимать запрос и искать адресата, потом пересылать ему сообщения. Потом получатель превращается в отправителя и процесс повторяется. Может есть какие-то техники, практики как это реализовать или что-то в этом роде?

В данный момент пытаюсь понять как работает node js и смотрю примеры реализации онлайн чата. И все они почему-то начинаются с: "Смотрите как просто запустить сервер на ноде, всего 10 строчек кода". Но потом они почему-то накатывают на него в обязательном порядке express... но нет, подождите, нужно накатить ещё socket.io. И вот теперь сервер. А те 10 строчек это был ещё значит не сервер? В общем пока всё для меня как-то сумбурно в этом плане. А там ещё наверняка есть целый камаз с подводными камнями...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший плагин для поддержки push-уведомлений в phonegap можете найти здесь https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.

По поводу серверной части.
Раз вы делаете что-то вроде чата, то я не вижу смысла связываться с классическим веб-сервером. Т.е. ни express, ни другие подобные библиотеки вам не нужны. Если вас устроят Android 4.4+ и IOS 8+, то можете всё выполнить через websocket-сервер, используя npm модуль `websocket`. Если нужна поддержка более старых версий ОС, в которых не поддержки websocket-клиента, то хорошим решением будет тот же `socket.io` или `sockjs` (можно даже в связке `sockjs` (для старых ОС) + `websocket` (для ОС с поддержкой websocket)).

Для отправки push-сообщений (через APNS или GCM) вам понадобится на сервере делать http-запросы на https сервера Apple или Google. Можете это делать встроенными в node средствами (библиотека `https`) или воспользоваться более удобными библиотеками, например, `superagent`.